# Eclipse RCP: list of running plugins

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, app-startup

I'm trying to improve my RCP application startup time.
The startup time with 30 enabled plugins is different from the startup time with 10 enabled plugins, even though all my plugins are lazy initialized (so after the startup only 10 plugins are loaded according to my log).
I'm trying to understand what makes the difference so I'd like to see which plugins are currently running.
Is there any way to see a list of running plugins in Eclipse Debug view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Anton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2097228/anton) specified in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29791126/1544364), OSGi console indeed solves the problem. However there are several things to do before you can use the OSGi console associated with an instance of the application you're debugging.
First you need to include following dependencies in your product:

- **org.eclipse.equinox.console**
- **org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime**
- **org.apache.felix.gogo.command**
- **org.apache.felix.gogo.shell**

Once the dependencies are added, add **-console** argument to Program Arguments in your launching configuration.

That's it. Now you can launch your RCP application from within Eclipse, the OSGi commands are available in the regular console view associated with your application.
Thus, **ss** command lists all the loaded bundles and their status.

Answer (score 2):

How about using the OSGi console to list the plugins and their status? You can use the command `ss` which lists all the existing bundles in the OSGi environment. Bundle ID, State and Bundle symbolic name of all the bundles are shown.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what I want. When I use OSGi console it lists the plugins of current Eclipse instance (dev environment). I want to see the list of plugins in Debug instance (the program I'm developing).